# Qml 2.0 TableView with QAbstractItemModel and Context Menu

Tags: c++, qt, menu, qml, qt5

I have `TableView` from Qml 2.0 controls that is connected to `QAbstractItemModel`. I want to make a context menu that can change the properties or simply call methods of a concrete object from the model.

**Example:**

`QAbstractItemModel` has an `std::vector<Person>`. `Person` has a method `alter()` which makes some changes (any changes, it does not matter which ones exactly are changes, the point is that the we are able to call the method).

When there is a right click on the row, the menu appears with an item `Alter`.

All I was able to find is how to make the menu.

```
  rowDelegate: Item {
    Menu {
      id: myContextMenu
      MenuItem {text: "Alter"; onTriggered: {} }
    }
    MouseArea {
      id: longPressArea
      anchors.fill: parent
      acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
      onClicked: {
        if (mouse.button == Qt.RightButton)
          myContextMenu.popup()
      }
    }
  }
```

But I still don't know how to connect the menu with an exact object of the row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the delegate, you can refer to the item by using the `role.property` convention. 
The default role would be `display`. Of course the `Person` has to derive from `QObject`, and must be registered with the QML Engine.

The code below demonstrates how to:

1. Create a sensibly behaving `ObjectListModel` for storage of `QObjects`, usable from QML.
2. Create a `QObject`-derived class that keeps your data.
3. Access the properties and invokable methods of the data objects from a pop-up menu shown on the delegate.

The model can be set to automatically notify about changes to the properties of the contained QObjects. Such notifications, if resulting from bulk changes (say done in a loop) are coalesced and sent off as a single `dataChanged` event.

Unfortunately, the user property of a `QObject` acquires no special meaning - you still need to use the `.property` selector to access it.

Proper behavior of the model can be observed directly, since there are two lists hooked to the same model - they better showed the same thing.

The `ObjectListModel` could also implement a mapping between the roles and the properties. Currently, both the display and edit roles select the entire object, not any particular property of it.

If the storage of `QObject`s is too high of an overhead, an alternative model implementation could create `QObject` adapters to POD types on-the-fly.

[image: screenshot]

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QSet>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <functional>

class Person : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name NOTIFY nameChanged MEMBER m_name)
    QString m_name;
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE Person(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { setRandomName(); }
    Q_INVOKABLE Person(QString name, QObject * parent = 0) :
                       QObject(parent), m_name(name) {}
    Q_SIGNAL void nameChanged(const QString &);
    Q_INVOKABLE void setRandomName() {
        static const QString names = "Badger,Shopkeeper,Pepperpots,Gumbys,Colonel";
        static const QStringList nameList = names.split(',');
        QString newName = nameList.at(qrand() % nameList.length());
        if (newName != m_name) {
            m_name = newName;
            emit nameChanged(m_name);
        }
    }
};

class ObjectListModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(ObjectListModel)
    //! Whether changes to underlying objects are exposed via `dataChanged` signals
    Q_PROPERTY(bool elementChangeTracking
               READ elementChangeTracking WRITE setElementChangeTracking
               NOTIFY elementChangeTrackingChanged)
    QObjectList m_data;
    std::function<QObject*()> m_factory;
    bool m_tracking;
    QBasicTimer m_notifyTimer;
    QMap<int, char> m_notifyIndexes;
    //! Updates the property tracking connections on given object.
    void updateTracking(QObject* obj) {
        const int nIndex = metaObject()->indexOfSlot("propertyNotification()");
        QMetaMethod const nSlot = metaObject()->method(nIndex);
        const int props = obj->metaObject()->propertyCount();
        if (m_tracking) for (int i = 0; i < props; ++i) {
            const QMetaProperty prop = obj->metaObject()->property(i);
            if (prop.hasNotifySignal()) connect(obj, prop.notifySignal(), this, nSlot);
        } else {
            disconnect(obj, 0, this, 0);
        }
    }
    //! Receives property notification changes
    Q_SLOT void propertyNotification() {
        int i = m_data.indexOf(sender());
        if (i >= 0) m_notifyIndexes.insert(i, 0);
        // All of the notifications will be sent as a single signal from the event loop.
        if (!m_notifyTimer.isActive()) m_notifyTimer.start(0, this);
    }
protected:
    //! Emits the notifications of changes done on the underlying QObject properties
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->timerId() != m_notifyTimer.timerId()) return;
        emit dataChanged(index(m_notifyIndexes.begin().key()),
                         index((m_notifyIndexes.end()-1).key()),
                         QVector<int>(1, Qt::DisplayRole));
        m_notifyTimer.stop();
        m_notifyIndexes.clear();
    }
public:
    //! A model that creates instances via a given metaobject
    ObjectListModel(const QMetaObject * mo, QObject * parent = 0) :
        QAbstractListModel(parent),
        m_factory([mo, this](){
            return mo->newInstance(Q_ARG(QObject*, this));
        }),
        m_tracking(false)
    {}
    //! A model that creates instances using a factory function
    ObjectListModel(const std::function<QObject*()> & factory,
                    QObject * parent = 0) :
        QAbstractListModel(parent), m_factory(factory), m_tracking(false)
    {}
    ~ObjectListModel() {
        qDeleteAll(m_data);
    }
    bool elementChangeTracking() const { return m_tracking; }
    void setElementChangeTracking(bool tracking) {
        if (m_tracking == tracking) return;
        for (QObject* obj : m_data) updateTracking(obj);
        emit elementChangeTrackingChanged(m_tracking = tracking);
    }
    Q_SIGNAL void elementChangeTrackingChanged(bool);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        return m_data.count();
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole) {
            return QVariant::fromValue(m_data.at(index.row()));
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
    Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        Q_UNUSED(role);
        QObject* object = value.value<QObject*>();
        if (!object) return false;
        if (object == m_data.at(index.row())) return true;
        delete m_data.at(index.row());
        m_data[index.row()] = object;
        emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>(1, role));
        return true;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE bool insertRows(int row, int count,
                                const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())
    Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1);
        for (int i = row; i < row + count; ++ i) {
            QObject * object = m_factory();
            Q_ASSERT(object);
            m_data.insert(i, object);
            updateTracking(object);
            QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(object, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
        }
        endInsertRows();
        return true;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE bool removeRows(int row, int count,
                                const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())
    Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1);
        while (count--) delete m_data.takeAt(row);
        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<Person>();
    ObjectListModel model1(&Person::staticMetaObject);
    model1.setElementChangeTracking(true);
    model1.insertRows(0, 1);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("model1", &model1);
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300; height: 300
    Row {
        width: parent.width
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: row2.top
        Component {
            id: commonDelegate
            Rectangle {
                width: view.width
                implicitHeight: editor.implicitHeight + 10
                border.color: "red"
                border.width: 2
                radius: 5
                TextInput {
                    id: editor
                    anchors.margins: 1.5 * parent.border.width
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: edit.name // "edit" role of the model, to break the binding loop
                    onTextChanged: {
                        display.name = text; // set the name property of the data object
                    }
                }
                Menu {
                  id: myContextMenu
                  MenuItem { text: "Randomize"; onTriggered: display.setRandomName() }
                  MenuItem { text: "Remove"; onTriggered: model1.removeRows(index, 1) }
                }
                MouseArea {
                  id: longPressArea
                  anchors.fill: parent
                  acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
                  onClicked: myContextMenu.popup()
                }
            }
        }
        spacing: 2
        ListView {
            id: view
            width: (parent.width - parent.spacing)/2
            height: parent.height
            model: DelegateModel {
                id: delegateModel1
                model: model1
                delegate: commonDelegate
            }
            spacing: 2
        }
        ListView {
            width: (parent.width - parent.spacing)/2
            height: parent.height
            model: DelegateModel {
                model: model1
                delegate: commonDelegate
            }
            spacing: 2
        }
    }
    Row {
        id: row2
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        Button {
            text: "Add Page";
            onClicked: model1.insertRows(delegateModel1.count, 1)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project based on Kuba Ober answer. I also created a commodity class called QQuickList, that inherits QList and integrates a QObjectListModel. Enjoy.

https://github.com/Murazaki/QObjectListModel-QQuickList